# Accessing the contact Content Provider

Tags: android

I am just tring to access the contact Content Provider. for that i wrote following code

```
Cursor cur= getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,null);

    startManagingCursor(cur);

    String[] result=new String[cur.getCount()];

    if(cur.moveToFirst())
    {
        int nameidx=cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int Ididx=cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
        String strName=cur.getString(nameidx);
        String strId=cur.getString(Ididx);

        result[cur.getPosition()]=strName+"("+strId+")";
    }while(cur.moveToNext());

   stopManagingCursor(cur);
}
```

but its showing only one contact name i want to show all contact available please tell me how do that.

Comment: Are you sure about the "while" ? I think the problem is here

Comment: where is your do statement??????

Comment: actually i missed my do statement that was the problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead

```
Cursor cur= getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,null);

startManagingCursor(cur);

String[] result=new String[cur.getCount()];

for (boolean hasData = cursor.moveToFirst(); hasData; hasData = cursor.moveToNext())
{
    int nameidx=cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int Ididx=cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
    String strName=cur.getString(nameidx);
    String strId=cur.getString(Ididx);

    result[cur.getPosition()]=strName+"("+strId+")";
}
stopManagingCursor(cur);
}
```

Comment: can you tell me rather thans retriving _id can i retrive phone number directly??????????