# getting limited contacts from content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm working on getting contacts from contact content provider. Are there any way that I can get limited number of contacts and display it. I need to get first 50 contacts and display in list and once the list scroll into the last one, load another extra 50 contacts append to the list. Thanks

Comment: What programming language what software. there question is not very detailed. And i may be wrong but this doesnt seem like a programing question. it would be better on [Superuser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: @09stephenb: In android only. Are there any way that we can query the content provider to get limited number of contacts.

Comment: Is this question programming related if not put it on [superuser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: @09stephenb: Yes it is. We usually work on getting contacts from content provider right? It always get the cursor of contacts. But my question is, are there any code which fetches and loads the contacts asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to split your problem up into parts:

1. Query the ContentProvider for contacts, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089991/accessing-the-contact-content-provider).
2. Provide the cursor into a CursorAdapter.
3. Set the adapter onto a ListView.

The native behavior of CurorAdapter is to dynamically load items from a cursor as the user scrolls, so loading more, as you describe, as the user encounters the end of the list is likely not needed.